# Fibonacci - I am stuck

Tags: python

so I am new in programming (as you will see from my silly question). 
I am really stuck with this bit:

```
def Fibonnaci():
    num = int(raw_input("How many numbers? "))
    i = 1
    if num ==0:
        fib = []
    elif num ==1:
        fib = [1]
    elif num ==2:
        fib = [1,1]
    elif num >2:
        fib = [1,1]
    while i < (num - 1):
        fib.append(fib[i] + fib[i -1])
        i += 1
    return fib
print Fibonnaci()
```

What I don’t get is the `fib.append(fib[i] + fib[i-1])`

So lets say the number I selected in the input is `5`. So the `fib` list will have `[1,1]` in. Then the `i` will be `1`. Now I get confused. If the `i` in `fib[i]` is `1`, then the `i-1` is `0`. `1+0` is `1` and the print out should then be `[1,1,1,3,5]`. This actually happened when I removed the `fib`. and left it only as `fib.append(i+(i-1))`.

So I presume the `fib` is doing something important but I cant figure out what. Because at this point `i = 1`. So how does the list get the `2` there? The output is `1,1,2,3,5`.
Even if the `fib[i]` would mean that the `i` is now `2` as there are `[1,1]` in the list, then it would go `2+1 = 3` hence the `fib` would now be `[1,1,3]`.

I hope I haven’t confused you completely (because I am confusing myself).

Comment: Are you trying to write a program that prints Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: If `i==1`, then `fib[i] == fib[1] == 1` and `fib[i-1] == fib[0] == 1`. Therefore, `fib[i] + fib[i-1] == 1 + 1 == 2`, and the list is modified as `fib.append(2)`.

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence starts with 1, 1, 2, 3, 5; starting from 1, 1, you add those two numbers and result at 2, and add this into the list.  I'm not exactly in a place to test your code specifically, but are you saying that the array contains 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 and you expect it to contain 1, 1, 3, 5 instead?

Comment: @Makoto (and others): It seems the OP is trying to understand someone else's existing code, but cannot see how it works. I see some confusion between `fib`, `fib[i]` and `i` . . .

Comment: The code works, but I dont know how this works:

Comment: fib = [1,1] since num >2.  That makes fib[0]=1 and fib[1]=1. When i=1 it become fib.append(1+1) which makes fib = [1,1,2].

Comment: "then the i-1 is 0" here is the problem of your description, the algorithm is adding fib[0] (which is 1), not 0 itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one writes `fib[i]` it means the expression is expanded to **the value in list `fib` on index `i`**. So say we have constructed `fib` and it is:

```
fib = [1,1]
```

## The first iteration

now `i = 1` and we execute the line:

```
fib.append(fib[i]+fib[i-1])
```

Now what does this mean, first the expression is expanded by substituting `i` into `1`, we thus read:

```
fib.append(fib[1]+fib[1-1])
```

or

```
fib.append(fib[1]+fib[0])
```

Now the second (lists start at index `0`) value of `fib` (`fib[1]`) is `1` and so is the first element (`fib[0]`) so we expand this to:

```
fib.append(1+1)
```

or:

```
fib.append(2)
```

Now Python will perform this action and `fib` now is:

```
fib = [1,1,2]
```

## The second iteration

After `fib` is altered, `i` is updated (now `i = 2`), and so we go for the next iteration. In this iteration we again perform:

```
fib.append(fib[i]+fib[i-1])
```

since `i=2`, we can substitute this for:

```
fib.append(fib[2]+fib[1])
```

Now the third (`fib[2]`) and the second (`fib[1]`) element of the list are `1` and `2` respectively (you can check this from the end of the previous section), and thus Python will run:

```
fib.append(2+1)
```

which is thus equivalent to:

```
fib.append(3)
```

So after this iteration, `fib` is equal to:

```
fib = [1,1,2,3]
```

This process is repeated until `i` gets to the bound. So each time, Python reads the *last two* elements of the `fib` list constructed this far, adds them together and adds this at the end of the list (`fib`). Finally if the bound is reached, the result is returned.

Comment: Oh I see! So the i in this case really refers to the position in the list and not the number as such. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Loki: indeed. The position is usually called the *index* in computer science.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is only a counter here. The last part could be changed this way:

```
# we need to repeat n-2 times (i.e. once for a list of 3)
for i in range(num-2):
    # fib is the array of numbers we already have
    # we append sum of the last two elements n-2 times
    fib.append(fib[-1] + fib[-2])  
return fib
```

In the original example, since `i` is the same as the length of `fib`, it is used as index. So, `fib[i]` is the last element and `fib[i-1]` is the last but one

Comment: I think what the OP is missing here is the concept of the *index* of a list, by introducing negative indices, I don't think we make it easier for the OP to understand how this works.

Comment: Yes, I didnt realise it was using the index. Got it now. Should have seen it really:) Thanks guys